# Fixing Python Custom `get_last_period_values()` Function

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to build a function (currently shown as `get_last_period_values()` in the below script) that gets the prior period value - e.g., you may want to values of 1 month prior to current, or 3 months prior, etc...

Below is my current script, but I keep getting errors, resolving those errors, just to get more errors... It's just an infinite loop of new errors happening after each I solve...

In addition, pandas `.pct_change()` method isn't sufficient for what I need, as I'm trying to get the precise values for the prior period.

The below contains the script itself that's ready to run and input values within the script. Then the desired output is found below the script!

Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
import pandas as pd
import io 

## CONSTANTS ##
MONTHS_1 = 1
MONTHS_12 = 12

## CSV ##
INPUT_CSV = """
URL,Organic Keywords,Organic Traffic,Date
https://www.example-url.com/,1315,11345,20231115
https://www.example-url.com/,1183,5646,20231015
https://www.example-url.com/,869,5095,20230915
https://www.example-url.com/,925,4574,20230815
https://www.example-url.com/,899,4580,20230715
https://www.example-url.com/,1382,5720,20230615
https://www.example-url.com/,1171,5544,20230515
https://www.example-url.com/,1079,5041,20230415
https://www.example-url.com/,734,3855,20230315
https://www.example-url.com/,853,3455,20230215
https://www.example-url.com/,840,2343,20230115
https://www.example-url.com/,325,2318,20221215
https://www.example-url.com/,156,1981,20221115
https://www.example-url.com/,166,2059,20221015
https://www.example-url.com/,124,1977,20220915
https://www.example-url.com/,98,1919,20220815
https://www.example-url.com/,167,1796,20220715
https://www.example-url.com/,140,1596,20220615
https://www.example-url.com/,168,1493,20220515
https://www.example-url.com/,171,1058,20220415
https://www.example-url.com/,141,1735,20220315
https://www.example-url.com/,129,1836,20220215
https://www.example-url.com/,141,746,20220115
https://www.example-url.com/,129,1076,20211215
"""

## HELPERS ##
def get_last_period_values(df, months_prior):
    df['Date_Prior'] = df['Date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=months_prior)
    merged_df = df.merge(
        df[['Date', 'Organic Keywords', 'Organic Traffic']],
        left_on='Date_Prior',
        right_on='Date',
        suffixes=('_' + str(months_prior) + 'mo_Prior', ''),
        how='left'
    )
    merged_df = merged_df.drop(columns=['Date_Prior'])
    return merged_df

## MAIN ##

# Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(INPUT_CSV))

# Convert the "Date" column to date format
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')

# Sort the DataFrame by date in desc order
df = df.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)

# Calculate the 1-month prior values
df_1mo = get_last_period_values(df, MONTHS_1)

# Calculate the 12-month prior values
df_12mo = get_last_period_values(df, MONTHS_12)

# Merge the DataFrames together
merged_df = df.merge(df_1mo, on='Date', suffixes=('', '_1mo_Prior'))
merged_df = merged_df.merge(df_12mo, on='Date', suffixes=('', '_12mo_Prior'))

# Display the merged DataFrame
print(merged_df)
```

the desired output from the script would be the below:

```
DESIRED_OUTPUT_CSV = """
URL,Date,Organic_Keywords,Organic_Traffic,Date_12mo_Prior,Organic_Keywords_12mo_Prior,Organic_Traffic_12mo_Prior,Date_1mo_Prior,Organic_Keywords_1mo_Prior,Organic_Traffic_1mo_Prior
https://www.example-url.com/,11/15/2023,1315,11345,11/15/2022,156,1981,10/15/2023,1183,5646
https://www.example-url.com/,10/15/2023,1183,5646,10/15/2022,166,2059,9/15/2023,869,5095
https://www.example-url.com/,9/15/2023,869,5095,9/15/2022,124,1977,8/15/2023,925,4574
https://www.example-url.com/,8/15/2023,925,4574,8/15/2022,98,1919,7/15/2023,899,4580
https://www.example-url.com/,7/15/2023,899,4580,7/15/2022,167,1796,6/15/2023,1382,5720
https://www.example-url.com/,6/15/2023,1382,5720,6/15/2022,140,1596,5/15/2023,1171,5544
https://www.example-url.com/,5/15/2023,1171,5544,5/15/2022,168,1493,4/15/2023,1079,5041
https://www.example-url.com/,4/15/2023,1079,5041,4/15/2022,171,1058,3/15/2023,734,3855
https://www.example-url.com/,3/15/2023,734,3855,3/15/2022,141,1735,2/15/2023,853,3455
https://www.example-url.com/,2/15/2023,853,3455,2/15/2022,129,1836,1/15/2023,840,2343
https://www.example-url.com/,1/15/2023,840,2343,1/15/2022,141,746,12/15/2022,325,2318
https://www.example-url.com/,12/15/2022,325,2318,12/15/2021,129,1076,11/15/2022,156,1981
https://www.example-url.com/,11/15/2022,156,1981,,,,10/15/2022,166,2059
https://www.example-url.com/,10/15/2022,166,2059,,,,9/15/2022,124,1977
https://www.example-url.com/,9/15/2022,124,1977,,,,8/15/2022,98,1919
https://www.example-url.com/,8/15/2022,98,1919,,,,7/15/2022,167,1796
https://www.example-url.com/,7/15/2022,167,1796,,,,6/15/2022,140,1596
https://www.example-url.com/,6/15/2022,140,1596,,,,5/15/2022,168,1493
https://www.example-url.com/,5/15/2022,168,1493,,,,4/15/2022,171,1058
https://www.example-url.com/,4/15/2022,171,1058,,,,3/15/2022,141,1735
https://www.example-url.com/,3/15/2022,141,1735,,,,2/15/2022,129,1836
https://www.example-url.com/,2/15/2022,129,1836,,,,1/15/2022,141,746
https://www.example-url.com/,1/15/2022,141,746,,,,12/15/2021,129,1076
https://www.example-url.com/,12/15/2021,129,1076,,,,,,
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do this. Here is the completed script. Works perfectly for anyone else that's trying to accomplish this! :)

I added in some extra functionality from the initial request as well, so you get both the "absolute" and "relative" (%) change for the comparison period!

```
import pandas as pd
import io 

## CONSTANTS ##
INITIAL_COL_REORDER = ['URL', 'Date', 'Organic Keywords', 'Organic Traffic']
METRIC_COLS = ['Organic Keywords', 'Organic Traffic']
DIMENSION_COLS = ['URL']
DATE_COL = 'Date'
MONTHS_1 = 1
MONTHS_3 = 3
MONTHS_12 = 12
PERIODS = [1, 3, 12]

INPUT_CSV = """
URL,Organic Keywords,Organic Traffic,Date
https://www.example-url.com/,1315,11345,20231115
https://www.example-url.com/,1183,5646,20231015
https://www.example-url.com/,869,5095,20230915
https://www.example-url.com/,925,4574,20230815
https://www.example-url.com/,899,4580,20230715
https://www.example-url.com/,1382,5720,20230615
https://www.example-url.com/,1171,5544,20230515
https://www.example-url.com/,1079,5041,20230415
https://www.example-url.com/,734,3855,20230315
https://www.example-url.com/,853,3455,20230215
https://www.example-url.com/,840,2343,20230115
https://www.example-url.com/,325,2318,20221215
https://www.example-url.com/,156,1981,20221115
https://www.example-url.com/,166,2059,20221015
https://www.example-url.com/,124,1977,20220915
https://www.example-url.com/,98,1919,20220815
https://www.example-url.com/,167,1796,20220715
https://www.example-url.com/,140,1596,20220615
https://www.example-url.com/,168,1493,20220515
https://www.example-url.com/,171,1058,20220415
https://www.example-url.com/,141,1735,20220315
https://www.example-url.com/,129,1836,20220215
https://www.example-url.com/,141,746,20220115
https://www.example-url.com/,129,1076,20211215
"""


## HELPER FUNCTION ##
def get_last_period_values(df, months_prior, metric_cols, dimension_cols, date_col):
    df_copy = df.copy()
    df_copy[f'{date_col}_Prior'] = df_copy[date_col] - pd.DateOffset(months=months_prior)
    
    # get the values from the previous period and merge them into the current dataframe
    df_copy = df_copy.merge(
        df_copy[[date_col] + dimension_cols + metric_cols], 
        left_on=f'{date_col}_Prior', 
        right_on=date_col, 
        how='left',
        suffixes=('', f'_{months_prior}mo_Prior')
    )
    
    # drop _prior date col and any prior cols from merge for 'dimension_cols'
    df_copy = df_copy.drop(columns=[f'{date_col}_Prior'] + [col + f'_{months_prior}mo_Prior' for col in dimension_cols])
    
    # get absolute change for each metric
    for metric in metric_cols:
        df_copy[f'{metric}_{months_prior}mo_Abs_Change'] = df_copy[metric] - df_copy[f'{metric}_{months_prior}mo_Prior']
    
    # get percent change for each metric
    for metric in metric_cols:
        df_copy[f'{metric}_{months_prior}mo_Pct_Change'] = df_copy[metric] / df_copy[f'{metric}_{months_prior}mo_Prior'] - 1
        df_copy[f'{metric}_{months_prior}mo_Pct_Change'] = df_copy[f'{metric}_{months_prior}mo_Pct_Change'].round(2)
    
    return df_copy

def get_period_values(df, periods, metric_cols, dimension_cols, date_col):
    df_copy = df.copy()
    for period in periods:
        df_copy = get_last_period_values(df_copy, period, metric_cols, dimension_cols, date_col)
    return df_copy

## MAIN SCRIPT ##
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(INPUT_CSV))
    df = df[INITIAL_COL_REORDER]
    df[DATE_COL] = pd.to_datetime(df[DATE_COL], format='%Y%m%d')
    df = df.sort_values(by=DATE_COL, ascending=False)

    df_final = get_period_values(df, PERIODS, METRIC_COLS, DIMENSION_COLS, DATE_COL)

    # Display and Save the Final DataFrame
    print(df_final)
```